# Need a Gridview to Change when DropDownList changes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist in ASP.Net (I am using VB.Net) and my ASP.Net code follows.  What I would like to do is have that Girdview populate dynamically off of the DropDownList.  If the first option (showing nothing) is chosen, I would like everything possible in the Gridview to show.  If one of the other options is chosen, I would like the GridView to filter based on that option.  I can see the DropDownList, but nothing shows up in the Gridview.  I imagine the issue has to do with binding the DropDownList to the Gridview somehow.

Thanks in advance.

```
    <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB"  AutoEventWireup="true"      CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="SAP._Default" %>


    <%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="cc1" %>



    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title>Tab Container Tips & Tricks</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>   

         <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <cc1:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">

            <cc1:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" HeaderText="Screening">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Pull For Screening "></asp:Label>



    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"><asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>



    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add Applicants" />



                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Choose Campus: "></asp:Label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                         <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>RC</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>HS</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>TL</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>PH</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ScreenerView %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ScreenerView.ProviderName %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [ScreenerID], [LEGAL_FNAME], [LEGAL_LNAME], [APPL_PERSON_ID], [AAMC_ID], [GENDER], [URM], [RecMCAT], [SciGPA], [LEGAL_RES_STATE_CD], [PullDate], [First] FROM [vw_Screener]" 
                        FilterExpression="Screener ID LIKE '?' AND First LIKE '?'">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="intS" />
                        </SelectParameters>

                        <FilterParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2"   PropertyName="SelectedValue" />

          </FilterParameters> 
    </asp:SqlDataSource>


                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                        <Columns>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="ScreenerID" HeaderText="ScreenerID"   SortExpression="ScreenerID" Visible="False"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LEGAL_FNAME" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="LEGAL_FNAME" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LEGAL_LNAME" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LEGAL_LNAME" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="APPL_PERSON_ID" HeaderText="APPL_PERSON_ID" SortExpression="APPL_PERSON_ID" Visible="False" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="AAMC_ID" HeaderText="AAMC" SortExpression="AAMC_ID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="GENDER" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="GENDER" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="URM" HeaderText="URM" SortExpression="URM" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="RecMCAT" HeaderText="MCAT" SortExpression="RecMCAT" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="SciGPA" HeaderText="Sci. GPA" SortExpression="SciGPA" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LEGAL_RES_STATE_CD" HeaderText="State" SortExpression="LEGAL_RES_STATE_CD" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="PullDate" HeaderText="Date Pulled" DataFormatString = "{0:d}"   SortExpression="PullDate" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="First" HeaderText="First Choice CC" SortExpression="First" />
</Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
     </asp:GridView>




     </ContentTemplate>




    </cc1:TabPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your FilterExpression and FilterParements in your SQLDataSource:

**In your ASPX File** you need to make the following changes:

**FilterParameters:** The items in this list will be used by the FilterExpression. If this is emtpy then your FilterExpression will have nothing to work with. However, you have ONE item in there, now you must link it to the FilterExpression with its index. Since you have ONE item then its index will be 0 (see filterexpression below). I assume its the [ScreenerID] so its probably an Int32? Then you need to specify that and set a defaultvalue:

```
<FilterParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="ScreenerID" ControlID="DropDownList2"
    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="" />
</FilterParameters>
```

**FilterExpression:** The way you have it now is not correct because it is NOT linked with any real value say User-Interace (Dropdown) . You must link it based on its index/position in the FilterParameter items. Like we said above, since ScreenerID is the first item then it has index 0:

```
FilterExpression="ScreenerID = {0}"
```

**DropDownList2:** Since you already have `AutoPostBack="True"` you just need add event  `OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged"`

If ScreenID is an integer, you need to remove the % from the value field in the ALL item like so: `<asp:ListItem Value="" Text="ALL>`

**VB.NET Code-Behind:** In your `DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged` event dont put any code in it. Like so:

```
Protected Sub DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList2.SelectedIndexChanged    
    'Leave empty
End Sub
```

Let me know if this is not working for you, I can update this answer as I find out more from you.

Comment: LucidGold, thank you for your response.  I now have code that reads (in part) as follows:                        <FilterParameters>
                            <asp:SessionParameter Name="ScreenerID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="20"/>      The page loads okay, but there isn't any data in the gridview.  It is obviously processing when I change the dropdown.  Thank you for your assistance!
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" DefaultValue=""/>

          </FilterParameters>

Comment: One last question -- Do i need to add anything in the Code Behind?  I am using VB.Net

Comment: I added a few more updates to make answer more clear

Comment: In your db are you sure ScreenerID is an Int?